# tcpListener on Win 10 iOT not working

Tags: iot, tcplistener

I have a UWA on RPi 3 with Win 10 version 10.0.14393.0 and VS 2015 Update 3. I'm trying to run a TCPListener on my RPi, code runs with no exception but never can connect it, seems that some things block my connection. there is no hardware or software Firewall in path. I tried both background and foreground app but no result.

My code is as below :

```
namespace TestBackPort
{
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = null;

        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.9"), 1100);
        tcpListener.Start();
        var task = HandleConnectionsAsync(tcpListener);
        task.Wait();

    }

    int connectionNumber = 0;
    async Task HandleConnectionsAsync(TcpListener listener)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            // Console.WriteLine("OK #" + connectionNumber);
            connectionNumber++;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is solved, and it is the answer below that solved it, please click the tick mark adjacent to the answer. We do not use [solved] title hacks here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check your network state using "netstat" utility.

- Connect to your raspberry pi using putty or powershell
- Do "netstate -a" to verify that the TCP server is actually listening on that port.
- When you have your server running, you should see something similar to below
  [image]

Secondly, make sure you have the Internet Server capability enabled in the project manifest file. It could be either the Internet or the Private Networks, like below.
[image]